# How to design API endpoints for post a child object and for getting all the children of all the parents?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

For example I have entities: Client, Report. Client may have many Reports and I think the endpoint for a single Report management should be nested like this:

```
/clients/{client_id}/reports/{report_id}
```

As for all the reports of one client the enpoint is expected:

```
/clients/{client_id}/reports
```

But how should look an endpoint for getting all the Reports of all the Clients to keep API consistent and well designed.

My approaches:

1. (I saw it in some google api) use "-" instead of it and parse it as "all":

`/clients/-/reports`

This keeps endpoint format the same, but looks a bit unusal, can't find any rfc that suggest this way.

2. Make a separate endpoint just for all the reports:

`/reports`

But to get Client's Reports it's still:

`/clients/{client_id}/reports`

3. Refactor endpoints to make "client" not a parent, but just a filter parameter:

`/reports?client={client_id}`  - reports of one client

`/reports` - reports of all the client

In case of adding a new endpoint for posting a report for a specific client, It may look ugly, because it will be a POST-request with a parameter in URL.

Is there any other suggestions of ideas?

Comment: You might be interested [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951419/what-are-best-practices-for-rest-nested-resources)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how should look an endpoint for getting all the Reports of all the
> Clients to keep API consistent and well designed.

Before anything else, remember that there are no golden rules for modelling RESTful APIs. All we have are best practices and conventions. That being said, the likely answer is -as usual- to choose the one that best meets your requirements and in this case, the one that best expresses your model.

So check the three options from the expressiveness.

#### #1 The "-" notation

This is a good idea. It allows us to express the condition *all `reports` pertaining to `clients`*. It's narrowing down the "query" to a specific set of *reports* (those located within the `clients` boundary).

It keeps the notion of hierarchy (belonging) all the time, so if `reports` can be found in different locations, this notation makes a big deal. For example:

- *All reports pertaining to clients* `/clients/-/reports`
- *All reports pertaining to departments* `/departments/-/reports`
- *All reports pertaining to employees* `/employees/-/reports`

However, to retrieve all reports available, the hierarchy doesn't provide any valuable advantage over the next option.

#### #2 Different URIs

If we don't need to communicate *boundaries/contexts/hierarchy* when retrieving *all reports available*, the following approach seems more reasonable.

The new URI (`/reports`) also leaves the possibility for *reports management*. Meanwhile, supporting `GET` and some filters should be enough.

Note that you still could do this `/reports?client={client_id}`.
Having different URI for the same resource is fine. I would call this *[robustness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)*.

#### #3 Reverting the hierarchy

I get the feeling that this approach doesn't meet your expectations. Plus, I think, It will bring you eventually to the starting point.

#### Conclusions

#1 and #2 are not mutually exclusive. You can implement both. Given the actual situation and according to the OP's premises, option #2 seems the way to go.

---

<sup>1: it's equivalent to `/clients/-/reports` I guess</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Google's API design patterns suggest using '-' in this scenario.

```
GET /clients/-/reports
```

Source:

https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/design_patterns#list_sub-collections

Comment: Far be it for me to disagree with the almighty Google, but I think I'd prefer something like  `/client/{client_id}/report/{report_id}` and `/clients/report/{report_id}`

Comment: @RobertHarvey why not just `/reports`?

Comment: @Laiv: That would imply all reports.  Refresh your page; I made a ninja edit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I mean, why not 2 different endpoints `/clients...`and `/reports`.

Comment: @Laiv: Wouldn't you still need to specify a client id anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it could be informed in the request body.

Comment: @Laiv: OK, but that just raises the question "Which parameters should I put in the request body?"

Comment: @Yann what do you think about what Robert's question. Would be possible to inform the client id for `POST /reports` in the request body or it would take you to change the `report`representation somehow?